# segfault when trying to access structure; compile option - gcc -std=c99

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to access a structure with a pointer to an integer , from main. But the program crashes. It needs to be built with "std=c99" option as it is the requirement in a test.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Results{
    int *A;
    int N;
};
struct Results solution(int A[], int N, int K) {
    struct Results result;
    // write your code in C99 (gcc 4.8.2)
    int* T = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    result.A = A;
    result.N = N;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < K)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if(i > 0)
            {
                T[i] = A[i-1];
            }
            else
            {
                T[0] = A[N-1];
            }
        }
        count++;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            A[i] = T[i];
        }
    };
    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = T[i];
    } 

    return result;

}

struct Results solution(int A[], int N, int K);

void main()
{
    int B[5] = {3,8,9,7,6};
    struct Results st;
    solution(B,sizeof(B),1);
}
```

The trouble is at line:
 " solution(B,sizeof(B),1);"
What am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) Why use a prototype _after_ the function definition (which implies declaration).

Comment: 1) @iharob has the right answer, but you should also remember to release the memory you allocated using `malloc`... and... why are you using `malloc`? Maybe you meant to write `result.N = T;` instead of `result.N = N;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see `sizeof(B)` would give the number of elements in `B` times the size of an `int`, use `sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0])` instead.

Comment: Yes @iharob. Thank you.